# get unselected list using jquery multi select box

Tags: jquery

i am using a [jquery multi select](http://quasipartikel.at/2009/05/10/jqueryui-multiselect/) box to show and move between two lists. i want to retrieve the list of elements which have not been selected. i am trying this right now:

```
var notSelected = $("#myList").find('option').attr('selected',false);
```

but when i try an alert, it gives me type of **notSelected** as **HTMLElement** . is this the right technique? how am i supposed to get the list from this? is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var notSelected = $("#myList").find('option').not(':selected');
var array = notSelected.map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

What you are doing is to set the `selected` attribute value of all options in `#myList` to false

Comment: It's not a standard drop-down list, SO i think we can't use "option:selected" property.

Comment: @IshanJain... Initially I also thought so after posting the answer... then tested it in the [demo site](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) - select an deselect elements and then in console try `$("#countries").find('option').not(':selected');`

Comment: i tried alert(notSelected[0]) and it gave me object HTMLElement. can i do something with it to get the appropriate list?

Comment: @user2739737 `notSelected` is a jQuery object containing the list of elements... so if you want an array of `option` elements then use `notSelected.get()`

Comment: notSelected.get() will give me an array of option elements. can i get an array of strings from that (strings which make up the text in the select box)

Comment: @user2739737 you want the text or the value of the option elements?

Comment: @user2739737 then `var notSelected = $("#myList").find('option').not(':selected');
var array = notSelected.map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use

```
var notSelected = $("option[selected='false']", "#myList")
```

Comment: getting undefined when i try to alert notSelected[0]